# installation error while downloading dlib file

Tags: python, pip, dlib

I am trying to download dlib module in python version 3.8.3

My pip version is 22.1

This is the error I got while I was trying to double the dlib module on my system-

```
Using cached dlib-19.24.0.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for dlib, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: dlib
  Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for dlib did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [61 lines of output]
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      running build_ext
      Building extension for Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:37:02) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)]
      Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7w8dbl2a\dlib_a6e65f9bc04843d0890216847fb50eca\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7w8dbl2a\dlib_a6e65f9bc04843d0890216847fb50eca\build\lib.win-amd64-3.8 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7w8dbl2a\dlib_a6e65f9bc04843d0890216847fb50eca\build\lib.win-amd64-3.8 -A x64'
      -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (message):
    
      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7w8dbl2a\dlib_a6e65f9bc04843d0890216847fb50eca\setup.py", line 222, in <module>
          setup(
        File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
          dist.run_commands()
        File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
          return orig.install.run(self)
        File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
          self.run_command('build')
        File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7w8dbl2a\dlib_a6e65f9bc04843d0890216847fb50eca\setup.py", line 134, in run
          self.build_extension(ext)
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7w8dbl2a\dlib_a6e65f9bc04843d0890216847fb50eca\setup.py", line 171, in build_extension
          subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
        File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7w8dbl2a\\dlib_a6e65f9bc04843d0890216847fb50eca\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7w8dbl2a\\dlib_a6e65f9bc04843d0890216847fb50eca\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.8', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7w8dbl2a\\dlib_a6e65f9bc04843d0890216847fb50eca\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.8', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure
```

The pip version also shows that the error is in installation and not in pip. I didn't include it in the error code because it became too long.

How can I fix this error ?

Comment: The package you are trying to install does not contain a Windows binary, and so `pip` is trying to compile it from source. As you have discovered, on Windows this is not always straightforward.  Unfortunately,  the usual advice: to download an unofficial Windows binary from Christoph Gohlke's site; does not apply here because it's not available there.

Comment: So does that mean I cant download the module ?

Comment: It means that to get `pip` to compile the module from source, you need someone who knows more about the MSC development ecosystem than I do to figure out why `cmake` is failing. You clearly have `cmake`, otherwise you would have got a different error message. But the root cause is somewhere in the long `cmake` log that you chose not to put in your question. Next step is to [edit] your question to include it. Without it not even an MSC expert can say what is wrong.